# std::getline for an ifstream, using parameter string or char *

Tags: c++, string

I am using `fstream` to read or write into a file.

I meet a problem regarding the function `ifstream::getline`. When I include `<string>`, then I can pass string as a parameter to the function, if not, I have to pass `char*` as the parameter. Can someone tell me why?

According to the description of the function, as I understand it, the right parameter waited should be `char*`. Is the `string` value converted to a `char*` here?

Comment: If you don't `#include <string>`, then the compiler doesn't even know that there's a `getline` function...

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) only accepts an `std::string` as a parameter.

Comment: i am sorry, I meant ifstream::getline

Comment: You are talking about two different things. The `getline` member function and the `getline` free function that comes with `<string>`. There is no conversion or whatever. They are different things that just happen to have the same name and similar functionality.

Comment: yes, you are right. i've mistaken and i didn't know that std contents the function <getline>, i'd like to ask for the member function in ifstream.

Answer (score 2):

String type isn't converted to `char*`. That's why `.c_str()` exists. But the std::string type will accept a `char*` as an initializer.

The two types aren't backwards compatible. `std::string`'s will accept `char*`'s but `char*`'s don't accept `std::string`'s.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of `std::getline()`:

```
std::istream::getline(char*, char = '\n'); // member function of istream
std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&, char = '\n'); // free function in <string>
```

When including the definition of `std::istream` you obviously get the member function. However, you'll need to include `<string>` to get the definition of `std::string` which also comes with its version of `std::getline()`.

Comment: The OP was asking about ifstream not istream

Comment: @chbchb55: `std::ifstream` doesn't declare a `getline()` member function. Its base class `std::istream` does, however.

Comment: You're right but you could have at least posted how to convert ifstream to istream in order to use getline, albeit an easy thing to do if you updated your answer it would be correctly answering the OP's question